# Add angular-trix to angularjs firebase app

Tags: angularjs, rich-text-editor, angular-trix

I am making an app using angular and firebase. I want to implement angular-trix editor so that users can post their own articles. But I don't know how to integrate angular-trix. I have included the js files and in app.js I have injected the 'angularTrix'.
`var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngAnimate', 'firebase', 'ngSanitize','angularTrix']);`

This is my html page.

```
<div>
<trix-editor ng-model="trix" angular-trix></trix-editor>
<button ng-click="save()">Save!</button></div>
```

and this is controller

```
app.controller('profileCtrl', ['$scope', "$routeParams", "$firebaseObject", "$sce", "Auth", function($scope, $firebaseObject, $routeParams, $rootScope, Auth, $sce) {
// Demo controller
console.log('In ctrl');

$scope.trix = '<p>Hello</p>';
$scope.save = function() {
  alert($scope.trix);
};}]);
```

[image: Result]
I don't know what I have to include in a controller. I want that when a user will press submit button, it should extract the HTML and save it to the firebase.

I know how to save data in firebase but not how to extract the HTML from AngularTrix.

A snippet of code of controller would be of much help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner html is stored in the model which you pass to the editor through `ng-model` attribute like this:

```
<trix-editor angular-trix ng-model="foo"></trix-editor>
```

Here, `foo` would have your markup:

```
angular.module('trixDemo', ['angularTrix']).controller('trixDemoCtrl',   function($scope) {
  $scope.foo = '<div>Hello world!</div>';
});
```

Small [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/24KpP6sjSCvKHLle9imM?p=preview)

Comment: It's not working. Nothing is showing up on the page.

Comment: Button is working but the there is no data showing up in the trix-editor

Comment: I have written all the controllers in controller.js and have in initiated app in app.js

Comment: Are you talking about the demo or your app? Because I've tried the demo in different browsers even, it works fine. I cannot debug your code remotely for you

Comment: Have you included trix.js, angular-trix directive and their css file to your application? Please read the [documentation](https://github.com/sachinchoolur/angular-trix)